# Image height in svg is higher than SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, viewbox

I'm developing my portfolio, and I want to insert some websites screen capture in mockups. I don't want to take care, each time I want to add a project, to integrate the screenshot of the project'site in a mockup on Photoshop, to generate a JPG image that I would include in my site. So I thought of a relatively simple solution, which would be to take a mockup in SVG, and integrate the image directly into it.

Here's the problem, the image is higher than the mockup, and I would like the height of my SVG to be automatic compared to the size of the image.

[image: SVG height]

The image under the SVG is showed because there's an `overflow: visible;` on the SVG. But the image in the SVG is over the content that follows the SVG:

[image: image over the following content]

To sum up, the SVG height must depend on the height of the image.

Here's the SVG code:

```css
/* 
* For you, so you can see the image
* Without it, the body if equal to the SVG height so you can't see the image
*/
body {
  min-height: 1300px;
}

/* SVG CODE */
svg {
  overflow: visible; /* So you can see the image, but the SVG height stay the same */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
svg image {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<svg id="adf1338b-c638-44c9-9dd0-93df7f9f46b1" data-name="Calque 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 2148 1237.39">
      <defs>
        <filter id="e71a6e13-91a7-4c48-8db4-fd9f3d7680f9" x="-13.7" y="-110.5" width="128.3" height="140.2" name="filter-2">
          <feOffset result="shadowOffsetOuter1" dx="7.8" dy="7.8" in="SourceAlpha"/>
          <feGaussianBlur result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="81.5" in="shadowOffsetOuter1"/>
          <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.06 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1"/>
        </filter>
        <linearGradient id="952164c2-8d50-4072-8fbc-1daf64a9f996" data-name="Dégradé sans nom" x1="752.65" y1="994.07" x2="753.65" y2="994.07" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -12, -1616691.37, 13126.84)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.04"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.04"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <filter id="cb01145d-084b-4051-a7b8-afc1075b337d" y="-94.6" width="100" height="107.1" name="filter-5">
          <feOffset result="shadowOffsetInner1" dy="1" in="SourceAlpha"/>
          <feComposite result="shadowInnerInner1" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1" in="shadowOffsetInner1" in2="SourceAlpha"/>
          <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.02 0" in="shadowInnerInner1"/>
        </filter>
        <linearGradient id="45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 2" x1="744.83" y1="994.07" x2="743.59" y2="994.07" gradientTransform="matrix(80, 0, 0, -12, -57419, 13126.84)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <stop offset="0"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="d6b5fdf2-09db-48a0-a136-a0968d72d8fd" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 3" x1="743.59" y1="994.07" x2="744.59" y2="994.07" gradientTransform="matrix(80, 0, 0, -12, -59486.95, 13126.84)" xlink:href="#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c"/>
        <linearGradient id="ff74df12-f810-4f37-96f0-568d0d222681" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 4" x1="752.65" y1="968.72" x2="753.65" y2="968.72" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -33.39, -1616692.1, 33656.27)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.07"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#eaeaea" stop-opacity="0.07"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.07"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="1b131c43-0dea-4a3e-b634-4bb33e458dcc" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 6" x1="753.15" y1="969.22" x2="753.15" y2="968.22" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -33.39, -1616692.1, 33656.27)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.07"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.07"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="dc83dd5d-fe7a-4f3c-96dc-f9b3dd530f96" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 7" x1="753.15" y1="969.22" x2="753.15" y2="968.22" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -33.39, -1616692.1, 33656.27)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.05"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.05"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <filter id="55d6f982-cfb0-43d5-b1ce-33840dcf898f" x="-0.1" y="-93.6" width="100.2" height="105.3" name="filter-13">
          <feOffset result="shadowOffsetInner1" dy="1" in="SourceAlpha"/>
          <feComposite result="shadowInnerInner1" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1" in="shadowOffsetInner1" in2="SourceAlpha"/>
          <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.03 0" in="shadowInnerInner1"/>
        </filter>
        <linearGradient id="0347f2e9-aa93-4a31-83dd-17fa4a18e4ef" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 8" x1="734.18" y1="984.18" x2="735.18" y2="984.18" gradientTransform="matrix(40, 0, 0, -16, -28499.14, 17037.76)" xlink:href="#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c"/>
        <linearGradient id="48a5c464-8edd-45c4-9ce5-a29ab784ca76" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 9" x1="735.17" y1="984.18" x2="734.17" y2="984.18" gradientTransform="matrix(40, 0, 0, -16, -28127.82, 17037.76)" xlink:href="#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c"/>
      </defs>
      <g id="77173500-bfe4-412c-9f4c-6d18bf82908b" data-name="Artboard">
        <g id="98dd64aa-035e-4372-81a9-808b5df3da43" data-name="macbook">
          <g id="2528bcce-59cd-406f-8223-417b9dc2b419" data-name="bg">
            <g filter="url(#e71a6e13-91a7-4c48-8db4-fd9f3d7680f9)">
              <path id="a7e121fd-8fcd-4e60-8f74-4eb6bbc3617a" data-name="path-1" d="M296.42,91H1850.58c34,0,43.53,0,58.17,4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33,37.33c4.92,14.64,4.92,24.17,4.92,58.17V1223.58c0,34,0,43.53-4.92,58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33,37.33c-14.64,4.92-24.17,4.92-58.17,4.92H296.42c-34,0-43.53,0-58.17-4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33-37.33c-4.92-14.64-4.92-24.17-4.92-58.17V191.42c0-34,0-43.53,4.92-58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33-37.33C252.89,91,262.43,91,296.42,91Z" transform="translate(0 -91)"/>
            </g>
            <path id="400dfe13-b733-4999-ba8f-7c75bc5675e2" data-name="path-1" d="M296.42,91H1850.58c34,0,43.53,0,58.17,4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33,37.33c4.92,14.64,4.92,24.17,4.92,58.17V1223.58c0,34,0,43.53-4.92,58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33,37.33c-14.64,4.92-24.17,4.92-58.17,4.92H296.42c-34,0-43.53,0-58.17-4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33-37.33c-4.92-14.64-4.92-24.17-4.92-58.17V191.42c0-34,0-43.53,4.92-58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33-37.33C252.89,91,262.43,91,296.42,91Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="#fff"/>
          </g>
          <path id="43c6a4ac-5af9-45b1-9c0a-e2b805fceea4" data-name="cam" d="M1070.5,133a6.5,6.5,0,1,1-6.5,6.5A6.5,6.5,0,0,1,1070.5,133Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="#f2f2f2"/>
          <g id="41b53099-7741-4f93-a5b1-bbc7d688aeca" data-name="Bottom">
            <g id="ed61ea5b-396c-4755-acc5-837900bb45dd" data-name="Rectangle-1">
              <polygon id="3f88510c-3940-406a-944f-ea423fac19a9" data-name="path-4" points="0 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 0 1204 0 1192" fill="#fff"/>
              <polygon id="12bddb6b-cf6b-4005-b437-57bd064462a3" data-name="path-4" points="0 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 0 1204 0 1192" fill="url(#952164c2-8d50-4072-8fbc-1daf64a9f996)"/>
              <g filter="url(#cb01145d-084b-4051-a7b8-afc1075b337d)">
                <polygon id="04c57957-d6c4-492a-af0d-9db3629d7056" data-name="path-4" points="0 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 0 1204 0 1192"/>
              </g>
            </g>
            <polygon id="9b3aec7b-87aa-41a2-8c6e-1a1021f35e95" data-name="gradient" points="2068 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 2068 1204 2068 1192" opacity="0.1" fill="url(#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c)" style="isolation: isolate"/>
            <polygon id="2b964d54-6675-4afb-a411-aa203a5eaca1" data-name="gradient" points="0 1192 80 1192 80 1204 0 1204 0 1192" opacity="0.1" fill="url(#d6b5fdf2-09db-48a0-a136-a0968d72d8fd)" style="isolation: isolate"/>
            <g id="0f4064a7-9754-48ad-8901-2956fe4271fa" data-name="bottom">
              <path id="6dfeff10-a16b-4114-9289-11ca4696184e" data-name="path-11" d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="#fff"/>
              <path id="6ac336ae-89f9-44e0-8892-088e108b9b0c" data-name="path-11" d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="url(#ff74df12-f810-4f37-96f0-568d0d222681)"/>
              <path id="929a00e3-5dc1-434b-9ea2-499bfffeb4b7" data-name="path-11" d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="url(#ff74df12-f810-4f37-96f0-568d0d222681)"/>
              <path id="41d1f204-371f-4006-b6e3-3ca8e55170a4" data-name="path-11" d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="url(#1b131c43-0dea-4a3e-b634-4bb33e458dcc)"/>
              <path id="3661128a-dd7f-4831-ad61-767d60316664" data-name="path-11" d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="url(#dc83dd5d-fe7a-4f3c-96dc-f9b3dd530f96)"/>
            </g>
            <g id="be6e6ca0-ae80-4cfd-951c-f15752bfa1f4" data-name="Combined-shape-29">
              <path id="0381728f-4162-474f-a8a6-a34825b87739" data-name="path-12" d="M908,1283h371v11c0,4.22-40,5-40,5H908s-40-.78-40-5v-11Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="#fff"/>
              <g filter="url(#55d6f982-cfb0-43d5-b1ce-33840dcf898f)">
                <path id="a04f8c46-600e-4f3d-a0d0-18aec2a64794" data-name="path-12" d="M908,1283h371v11c0,4.22-40,5-40,5H908s-40-.78-40-5v-11Z" transform="translate(0 -91)"/>
              </g>
            </g>
            <path id="45b417de-e8a7-48cf-9a51-a395e9f84f91" data-name="gradient" d="M868,1283h40v16s-40-.78-40-5Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" opacity="0.07" fill="url(#0347f2e9-aa93-4a31-83dd-17fa4a18e4ef)" style="isolation: isolate"/>
            <path id="c82d931c-b5dd-41df-8d28-8b31c0ddfc08" data-name="gradient" d="M1279,1283h-40v16s40-.78,40-5Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" opacity="0.07" fill="url(#48a5c464-8edd-45c4-9ce5-a29ab784ca76)" style="isolation: isolate"/>
          </g>
          <g id="868adc6d-b9e8-4932-87a6-1078d21ee680" data-name="~SCREEN-HERE~">
            <g id="c080d29c-08b9-42d3-99f9-b333604f0ed7" data-name="Rectangle">
              <rect id="61fb43be-48cd-4ec6-b11b-6f8c5a6f0202" data-name="path-15" x="264" y="79" width="1618" height="1010" fill="#d8d8d8"/>
            </g>
            <g>
              <g>
                <image width="1618" height="1010" transform="translate(264 79)" xlink:href="http://res.cloudinary.com/bastienrobert/image/upload/v1519135713/cover_copie_vcpfee.jpg" style="isolation: isolate; height: auto;"/>
                <rect id="aef89c73-ce68-4e7f-aa2a-40ef1cca19a7" data-name="rect-17" x="264" y="79" width="1618" height="1010" fill-opacity="0"/>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Sorry for the 6 meter long question.

Comment: y u no use preserveAspectRatio?

Comment: On the image or on the SVG ? With what property ?

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you are after. "But the image in the SVG is over the content that follows the SVG". What content is after the SVG?  Can you update your sample so that we can see what you mean?

Comment: The image inside the SVG is heighter than the SVG, I want the SVG size to be automatic, to depend of the image size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I've finally found a simple solution, not as good as I was looking for but more easy to use: I set an SVG mask, higher than the image. So it's now looking like this, here is the SVG code:

```
<svg id="adf1338b-c638-44c9-9dd0-93df7f9f46b1" data-name="Calque 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 2148 3031">
  <defs>
    <filter id="e71a6e13-91a7-4c48-8db4-fd9f3d7680f9" x="-13.7" y="-110.5" width="128.3" height="140.2" name="filter-2">
      <feOffset result="shadowOffsetOuter1" dx="7.8" dy="7.8" in="SourceAlpha"></feOffset>
      <feGaussianBlur result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="81.5" in="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.06 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1"></feColorMatrix>
    </filter>
    <linearGradient id="952164c2-8d50-4072-8fbc-1daf64a9f996" data-name="Dégradé sans nom" x1="752.65" y1="994.07" x2="753.65" y2="994.07" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -12, -1616691.37, 13126.84)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.04"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.04"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="cb01145d-084b-4051-a7b8-afc1075b337d" y="-94.6" width="100" height="107.1" name="filter-5">
      <feOffset result="shadowOffsetInner1" dy="1" in="SourceAlpha"></feOffset>
      <feComposite result="shadowInnerInner1" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1" in="shadowOffsetInner1" in2="SourceAlpha"></feComposite>
      <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.02 0" in="shadowInnerInner1"></feColorMatrix>
    </filter>
    <linearGradient id="45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 2" x1="744.83" y1="994.07" x2="743.59" y2="994.07" gradientTransform="matrix(80, 0, 0, -12, -57419, 13126.84)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
      id="d6b5fdf2-09db-48a0-a136-a0968d72d8fd"
      data-name="Dégradé sans nom 3"
      x1="743.59"
      y1="994.07"
      x2="744.59"
      y2="994.07"
      gradientTransform="matrix(80, 0, 0, -12, -59486.95, 13126.84)"
      xlink:href="#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c"></linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="ff74df12-f810-4f37-96f0-568d0d222681" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 4" x1="752.65" y1="968.72" x2="753.65" y2="968.72" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -33.39, -1616692.1, 33656.27)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#eaeaea" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="1b131c43-0dea-4a3e-b634-4bb33e458dcc" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 6" x1="753.15" y1="969.22" x2="753.15" y2="968.22" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -33.39, -1616692.1, 33656.27)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="dc83dd5d-fe7a-4f3c-96dc-f9b3dd530f96" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 7" x1="753.15" y1="969.22" x2="753.15" y2="968.22" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -33.39, -1616692.1, 33656.27)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.05"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.05"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="55d6f982-cfb0-43d5-b1ce-33840dcf898f" x="-0.1" y="-93.6" width="100.2" height="105.3" name="filter-13">
      <feOffset result="shadowOffsetInner1" dy="1" in="SourceAlpha"></feOffset>
      <feComposite result="shadowInnerInner1" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1" in="shadowOffsetInner1" in2="SourceAlpha"></feComposite>
      <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.03 0" in="shadowInnerInner1"></feColorMatrix>
    </filter>
    <linearGradient
      id="0347f2e9-aa93-4a31-83dd-17fa4a18e4ef"
      data-name="Dégradé sans nom 8"
      x1="734.18"
      y1="984.18"
      x2="735.18"
      y2="984.18"
      gradientTransform="matrix(40, 0, 0, -16, -28499.14, 17037.76)"
      xlink:href="#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c"></linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
      id="48a5c464-8edd-45c4-9ce5-a29ab784ca76"
      data-name="Dégradé sans nom 9"
      x1="735.17"
      y1="984.18"
      x2="734.17"
      y2="984.18"
      gradientTransform="matrix(40, 0, 0, -16, -28127.82, 17037.76)"
      xlink:href="#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c"></linearGradient>
    <mask id="e5f414aa-2dc3-4e7e-beb9-c2665256ed3c-large" x="264" y="79" width="1618" height="3050" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <g transform="translate(0 -91)">
        <g id="5c9c027a-7ae5-4592-a798-6d4ba66f4659" data-name="mask-16">
          <rect id="b88cc6a8-61b0-4014-b1dc-ffc15d65cac1" data-name="path-15" x="264" y="170" width="1618" height="3050" fill="#fff"></rect>
        </g>
      </g>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g id="77173500-bfe4-412c-9f4c-6d18bf82908b" data-name="Artboard">
    <g id="98dd64aa-035e-4372-81a9-808b5df3da43" data-name="macbook">
      <g id="2528bcce-59cd-406f-8223-417b9dc2b419" data-name="bg">
        <g filter="url(#e71a6e13-91a7-4c48-8db4-fd9f3d7680f9)">
          <path
            id="a7e121fd-8fcd-4e60-8f74-4eb6bbc3617a"
            data-name="path-1"
            d="M296.42,91H1850.58c34,0,43.53,0,58.17,4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33,37.33c4.92,14.64,4.92,24.17,4.92,58.17V1223.58c0,34,0,43.53-4.92,58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33,37.33c-14.64,4.92-24.17,4.92-58.17,4.92H296.42c-34,0-43.53,0-58.17-4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33-37.33c-4.92-14.64-4.92-24.17-4.92-58.17V191.42c0-34,0-43.53,4.92-58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33-37.33C252.89,91,262.43,91,296.42,91Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"></path>
        </g>
        <path
          id="400dfe13-b733-4999-ba8f-7c75bc5675e2"
          data-name="path-1"
          d="M296.42,91H1850.58c34,0,43.53,0,58.17,4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33,37.33c4.92,14.64,4.92,24.17,4.92,58.17V1223.58c0,34,0,43.53-4.92,58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33,37.33c-14.64,4.92-24.17,4.92-58.17,4.92H296.42c-34,0-43.53,0-58.17-4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33-37.33c-4.92-14.64-4.92-24.17-4.92-58.17V191.42c0-34,0-43.53,4.92-58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33-37.33C252.89,91,262.43,91,296.42,91Z"
          transform="translate(0 -91)"
          fill="#fff"></path>
      </g>
      <path id="43c6a4ac-5af9-45b1-9c0a-e2b805fceea4" data-name="cam" d="M1070.5,133a6.5,6.5,0,1,1-6.5,6.5A6.5,6.5,0,0,1,1070.5,133Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="#f2f2f2"></path>
      <g id="41b53099-7741-4f93-a5b1-bbc7d688aeca" data-name="Bottom">
        <g id="ed61ea5b-396c-4755-acc5-837900bb45dd" data-name="Rectangle-1">
          <polygon id="3f88510c-3940-406a-944f-ea423fac19a9" data-name="path-4" points="0 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 0 1204 0 1192" fill="#fff"></polygon>
          <polygon id="12bddb6b-cf6b-4005-b437-57bd064462a3" data-name="path-4" points="0 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 0 1204 0 1192" fill="url(#952164c2-8d50-4072-8fbc-1daf64a9f996)"></polygon>
          <g filter="url(#cb01145d-084b-4051-a7b8-afc1075b337d)">
            <polygon id="04c57957-d6c4-492a-af0d-9db3629d7056" data-name="path-4" points="0 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 0 1204 0 1192"></polygon>
          </g>
        </g>
        <polygon id="9b3aec7b-87aa-41a2-8c6e-1a1021f35e95" data-name="gradient" points="2068 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 2068 1204 2068 1192" opacity="0.1" fill="url(#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c)" style="isolation: isolate"></polygon>
        <polygon id="2b964d54-6675-4afb-a411-aa203a5eaca1" data-name="gradient" points="0 1192 80 1192 80 1204 0 1204 0 1192" opacity="0.1" fill="url(#d6b5fdf2-09db-48a0-a136-a0968d72d8fd)" style="isolation: isolate"></polygon>
        <g id="0f4064a7-9754-48ad-8901-2956fe4271fa" data-name="bottom">
          <path id="6dfeff10-a16b-4114-9289-11ca4696184e" data-name="path-11" d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="#fff"></path>
          <path
            id="6ac336ae-89f9-44e0-8892-088e108b9b0c"
            data-name="path-11"
            d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"
            fill="url(#ff74df12-f810-4f37-96f0-568d0d222681)"></path>
          <path
            id="929a00e3-5dc1-434b-9ea2-499bfffeb4b7"
            data-name="path-11"
            d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"
            fill="url(#ff74df12-f810-4f37-96f0-568d0d222681)"></path>
          <path
            id="41d1f204-371f-4006-b6e3-3ca8e55170a4"
            data-name="path-11"
            d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"
            fill="url(#1b131c43-0dea-4a3e-b634-4bb33e458dcc)"></path>
          <path
            id="3661128a-dd7f-4831-ad61-767d60316664"
            data-name="path-11"
            d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"
            fill="url(#dc83dd5d-fe7a-4f3c-96dc-f9b3dd530f96)"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="be6e6ca0-ae80-4cfd-951c-f15752bfa1f4" data-name="Combined-shape-29">
          <path id="0381728f-4162-474f-a8a6-a34825b87739" data-name="path-12" d="M908,1283h371v11c0,4.22-40,5-40,5H908s-40-.78-40-5v-11Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="#fff"></path>
          <g filter="url(#55d6f982-cfb0-43d5-b1ce-33840dcf898f)">
            <path id="a04f8c46-600e-4f3d-a0d0-18aec2a64794" data-name="path-12" d="M908,1283h371v11c0,4.22-40,5-40,5H908s-40-.78-40-5v-11Z" transform="translate(0 -91)"></path>
          </g>
        </g>
        <path id="45b417de-e8a7-48cf-9a51-a395e9f84f91" data-name="gradient" d="M868,1283h40v16s-40-.78-40-5Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" opacity="0.07" fill="url(#0347f2e9-aa93-4a31-83dd-17fa4a18e4ef)" style="isolation: isolate"></path>
        <path id="c82d931c-b5dd-41df-8d28-8b31c0ddfc08" data-name="gradient" d="M1279,1283h-40v16s40-.78,40-5Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" opacity="0.07" fill="url(#48a5c464-8edd-45c4-9ce5-a29ab784ca76)" style="isolation: isolate"></path>
      </g>
      <g id="868adc6d-b9e8-4932-87a6-1078d21ee680" data-name="~SCREEN-HERE~">
        <g id="c080d29c-08b9-42d3-99f9-b333604f0ed7" data-name="Rectangle">
          <rect id="61fb43be-48cd-4ec6-b11b-6f8c5a6f0202" data-name="path-15" x="264" y="79" width="1618" height="1010" fill="#d8d8d8"></rect>
        </g>
        <g mask="url(#e5f414aa-2dc3-4e7e-beb9-c2665256ed3c-large)">
          <g>
            <image width="1618" height="1010" transform="translate(264 79)" xlink:href="/images/capsule/cover.jpg" style="isolation: isolate; height: auto;"></image>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```